# Help in probability, Difficult Question://

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, sampling

Upon testing 80 resistors manufactured by a certain company,  it is found that 15 resistors failed to meet the tolerance design specifications

a)  Construct a 92%  two-sided confidence interval for the true fraction of resistors manufactured by the company that do meet the tolerance design specifications.

Comment: Please delete three of the four questions, and then show what you've tried in the remaining question

Comment: Success =80-15=65

Comment: It is more or less true. The probability that one resistor do meet the tolerance is $0.65$

Comment: P(s) =0.8125,P(f)=0.1875,1-alpha=0.92, alpha=0.08 ,alpha/2=0.04 ,z sub 0.04=1.41,.......it is one question with 4 parts so, sorry i can not del it

Comment: I posted an answer for a). I will delete the other questions for you. If you have questions according to b,c or d then you can ask a new questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $1-\alpha$ confidence interval for $\hat p$ is

$$\large{\left[ \hat p-z_{(1-\frac{\alpha}{2})} \cdot \sqrt{\frac{\hat p(1-\hat p)}{ n}} ,   \hat p+z_{(1-\frac{\alpha}{2})} \cdot \sqrt{\frac{\hat p(1-\hat p)}{ n}} \right]}$$

$z_{(1-\frac{\alpha}{2})}$ is the z-value of the standard normal distribution. $1-\alpha$ is the confidence level.

In your case $\hat p=0.65$ This is right.

$p(1-\hat p)=0.65\cdot 0.35$  and $1-\frac{\alpha}{2}=1-\frac{0.08}{2}=0.96$. Finally you know that $n=80$.

And $z_{0.96}=1.75$. Just look at the table for the [standard normal distribution](https://www.stat.tamu.edu/~lzhou/stat302/standardnormaltable.pdf).

I think with all the given values you can evaluate the bounds of the confidence interval.

Comment: GREAT,, Thankss alot for your helping: ))

Comment: @Justbelieve You´re welcome. I made an edit. $\hat p(1-\hat p)$ has to be also under the root.

Comment: Q plz can we use the "Confidence interval for the proportion " to find interval of failure??

Comment: @Justbelieve What is CIP ?

Comment: Q plz can we use the "Confidence interval for the proportion " to find interval of failure??

Comment: @Justbelieve Yes. Just replace $\hat p$ by $(1-\hat p)$. The expression under the root hasn´t to be changed because $(1-\hat p)\cdot \hat p=\hat p\cdot (1-\hat p)$

Comment: Okaay Great,,,  ☆